# Programmatically detect Mixed Content blocking in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does anyone know if it's possible to detect in JavaScript that Chrome has blocked content due to the Mixed Content restriction? I see that there is an error message in the Console, but this doesn't seem to be an exception, since using try/catch doesn't catch anything..

So the question is, how to detect that content has been blocked?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried serving up a JavaScript file from an insecure domain, that sets a global variable in the `window` object? Logically if the script was blocked, it wouldn't execute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that's an option for us, unfortunately.

Comment: If you include `<img src="http://...">` in your DOM structure, then use JavaScript (on DOM ready state) to get its width, then if it's 0 it failed to load. TMTOWTDI

Comment: Also, this sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- what are you ultimately trying to accomplish with this information?

Comment: Our site is running on https, and we have iframes that sometimes loads pages from http resources. In this case I want to detect that Chrome has blocked the content and display a message to the user. And just to get it out of the way: No we can't convert the http resources to https, it's out of our control. :)

Comment: @amphetamachine I tried your suggestion about using an image, unfortunately Chrome actually loads images from insecure resources, and only gives a warning in the log.

Comment: Maybe this method will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38026278/1682761

Comment: Would be useful for us too, but so far reading I see no solution. Mixed content blocking also occurs in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario where I blindly embed **iframes** that can be on *HTTP* or *HTTPS* domains. I've found a dirty workaround that does work, assuming the following:

- you have both *HTTP* and *HTTPS* versions of your website available.
- you have **jQuery** available

I've commented the code so it's easy to understand:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { /* when DOM is fully loaded */
        if ("https:" == window.location.protocol)
        { /* we are on the SSL (HTTPS) version of our website */
            $.each($("iframe"), function (k, iframe)
            { /* iterate through all iframes */
                if ("http:" == $(iframe).attr('src').substring(0, 5))
                { /* there's at least an iframe with non-SSL (HTTP) content (that will be blocked by the browser) */
                    /* lets redirect user to the non-SSL (HTTP) version of the website */
                    window.location = window.location.href.replace(/^https:\/\//ig, "http://");
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately we can't use this method since we only run our site in HTTPS.